# How to conditionally add attribute to an object?

Tags: javascript

I would like to conditionally add an attribute to an object. Currently I have this:

```
    const obj = {
    name: car.name,
    battery: car.battery && car.battery, 
    fuel: car.fuel && car.fuel
}
```

The problem is that if `car.battery` is not present I have `battery: undefined`. I would rather prefer not having that attribute in the object if it is not present. How can I achieve that?

Comment: `if (car.battery) obj.battery = car.battery;`…

Comment: Though, really… what are you doing here? You're just making a copy of the `car` object in a really verbose way.

Comment: If you want to solve this inline, you can use `battery: car.battery || 'something else if falsy'`. Beware though, that if `car.battery` is `0`, you will get `'something else if falsy'`

Answer (score 2):

> The problem is that if car.battery is not present I have battery:
>   undefined. I would rather prefer not having that attribute in the
>   object if it is not present.

Simply

```
const obj = Object.assign({}, car);
```

If `car` doesn't have *battery* or *fuel*, it won't get copied to `obj`